# Update var in ini file using bash

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a bash script to configure various aspects of a server. The context here is replacing a value of a variable in a conf file (ini format) with another value.

The context is

```
[ssh-iptables]

enabled = false
```

And I simply need to change false to true.

Typically I'd just do this with a simple bit of `sed`

```
sed -i 's/^enabled = false/enabled = true/g' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

But `enabled = false` exists in multiple places.

I've tried using `awk` with no success

```
awk -F ":| " -v v1="true" -v opt="enabled" '$1 == "[ssh-iptables]" && !f {f=1}f && $1 == opt{sub("=.*","= "v1);f=0}1' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

The above was sourced from [this forum thread](http://www.unix.com/302321572-post5.html) but I don't really have enough understanding of how to use it in scripts to make it work. All it seems to do is the equivalent of `cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`

I have found a few other scripts which are considerably longer which isn't ideal as this will happen to loads of ini files so I'm hoping someone can help me correct the above code or point me in the right direction.

Apologies if this belongs on ServerFault, but as it's scripting rather than the intricacies of server configuration itself I figured here might be more apt.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming your format is that there are no square-bracket lines (like `[ssh-iptables]`) within sections, I would use your solution above (with `sed`) but restrict the query to within that block like so:

```
sed -i '/^\[ssh-iptables\]$/,/^\[/ s/^enabled = false/enabled = true/' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

The extra part at the beginning tells the following substitution statement to only run between the line that is `[ssh-iptables]` and the next one that starts with a `[`. It uses two regular expressions separated by a comma which indicate the bounds.

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately. There is a line break between the `tables]` and the `enabled =` but removing it didn't make any difference. Does this care about line endings etc?

Comment: @BenSwinburne I accidentally transposed the location of the initial `^` when copying it here. It should work now.

Comment: It does indeed! Perfect. Thanks very much.

Comment: This is great, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me with the dollar sign after the closing ] for the section header. Any ideas why?

Comment: @deuberger If there's anything after the right square bracket on the line in your file (like a comment or even a space), it won't match. The dollar sign indicates "end of line".

Answer (score 17):

If you are open to use external applications, you could be interested into the use of `crudini`.

Example:

```
[oauth2provider]
module = SippoServiceOAuth2Provider
backend[] = none
wiface = public

; [calldirection]
; module = SippoServiceCallDirection
; backend[] = none
; wiface = internal
```

A standard grep will not filter commented exceptions.

With `crudini` things for consulting, setting and modify are easier:

```
$ crudini --get /myproject/config/main.ini oauth2provider wiface
public
$ crudini --get /myproject/config/main.ini calldirection wiface
Section not found: calldirection
```

I was on a bash-only app and moved to this approach. Just a suggestion.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using m4 instead of sed in this case.  This uses variable replacement and I think keeps the file looking readable.  Your m4 template might look like this:

```
[ssh-iptables]
enabled=SSH_IPTABLES_ENABLED
```

Now, you call m4 with the following parameters (which can be called from a bash script):

```
m4 -DSSH_IPTABLES_ENABLED=true input.m4 > output.ini
```

or:

```
m4 -DSSH_IPTABLES_ENABLED=false input.m4 > output.ini
```

This is an overly simple way of using m4, if you read about it you'll find you can do some really nifty things (this is the infrastructure upon which autoconf/automake was initially designed).

Comment: Unfortunately the default configuration of fail2ban on CentOS 6.4 creates the original `jail.conf` file which has the `enabled = true` so I'd have to script the replacement of true with `SSH_IPTABLES_ENABLED` anyway.

Comment: Usually with m4, you'd create a template library which you would execute against a configuration library for your various environments and /replace/ the existing config files, rather than edit the existing configuration in place.  There are advantages to both ways, and I do hope you settle on something that causes you few headaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^[ssh-iptables/ {ok=1}
     ok==1 && $0="enabled = false" {print "  enabled = true"; ok=0 ; next}
     {print $0} ' infile > tmp
     mv tmp infile
```