# How to add a line to a stanza if it doesn't exist already

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[TEST]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db

[TEST2]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234
```

Is there any way where I can grep each stanza to see if `DataSizeMB = 1234` is there? And if it's not, adding it to the stanza?

What I've tried:

```
cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"}/DataSizeMB/'
```

which grabs all the stanzas with `DataSizeMB`. I need to grep all stanzas without `DataSizeMB` and add the line.

An example output:

```
[TEST]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234

[TEST2]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234
```

Comment: What about just `grep "DataSizeMB = 1234" input_file`?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987648/update-var-in-ini-file-using-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one liner may help you, at least it could let you start:

```
awk -v RS="" -v pat="DataSizeMB = 1234"  '!($0~pat){$0=$0 ORS pat}$0=$0 ORS' file
```

(There would be an empty line appended to the file.)

Comment: The dreaded "pat" :-(. It's a **regexp** as you're using it, not a "pattern" (whatever that is!), though you should really be doing a string comparison `index($0,str)` rather than a regexp one since you don't actually want any chars evaluated as regexp metachars. More importantly, don't rely on `$0=$0 ORS` producing a string that awk will treat as non-null and non-zero. Only use an assignment in a conditional context if you **need** the result of that assignment to be evaluated as a condition to avoid any unexpected consequences. In this case use `{$0=$0 ORS}1`, not just `$0=$0 ORS`.

Comment: @EdMorton your comment is always valuable!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v str='DataSizeMB = 1234' '{print $0 (index($0,str) ? "" : "\n" str)}' file
[TEST]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234

[TEST2]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v var="DataSizeMB = 1234"  '
/^\[/ && value{
  if(found){
    print value
  }
  else{
    print value ORS var
  }
  found=value=""
}
$0 ~ var{
  found=1
}
NF{
  value=value?value ORS $0:$0
}
END{
  if(found){
    print value
  }
  else{
    print value ORS var
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @Alan C, could you please try this solution once, if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl, paragraph mode -00 in one-liner, that's what it is designed to solve such cases.

```
perl -00 -lpe ' BEGIN {$t="DataSizeMB = 1234" } $_.="\n$t" if ! /$t/ '
```

with Inputs

```
$ perl -00 -lpe ' BEGIN {$t="DataSizeMB = 1234" } $_.="\n$t" if ! /$t/ ' alanc.txt
[TEST]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234

[TEST2]
Path1 = db/test/testdb
Path2 = db/real/db
DataSizeMB = 1234


$
```