# Best way to alter a file in a bash script

Tags: bash

i have a file that have variables and values

objective: open the file and replace all id by input id

```
[FILE]
var1 = 2
id = 3
var3 = 5
id = 12
var4 = 5
```

and i can't replace the id values to new ones.

here's my code, any help or something will help. thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
uuid=$2

input="./$filename"

# awk -v find="id " -v field="5" -v newval="abcd" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="="} {if ($1 == find) $field=newval; print $1}' $input

while IFS= read -r line
do
    awk -v find="id " -v field="5" -v newval="abcd" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="="} {if ($1 == find) $field=newval;}' $input
    echo $line

done < "$input"
```

expected output

```
execute
./myscript.sh file.cnf 77 

expected output:
    [FILE]
var1 = 2
id = 77
var3 = 5
id = 77
var4 = 5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for adding your efforts. Could you please add sample of expected output in your question for better understanding, cheers.

Comment: Like so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987648/update-var-in-ini-file-using-bash  ?

Comment: but it's not working, i new in bash and i only want to find the id vars and replace value

Comment: Putting awk inside a shell loop is extreme inefficient: awk's purpose is to loop over the records of the input files. Also, your sample file has no line with a $5: please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you trying to edit the file, or output new text based on the file? Why don't you start with a description of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sed` is the right tool for this. You can even use its `-i` switch and update the file in-place.

```sh
$ cat file.txt
var1 = 2
id = 3
var3 = 5
id = 12
var4 = 5
```

```sh
$ NEW_ID=1234
$ sed -E "s/(id\s*=\s*)(.+)/\1${NEW_ID}/g" file.txt
var1 = 2
id = 1234
var3 = 5
id = 1234
var4 = 5
```

The string inside the quotes is a [`sed` script for substituting some text with different text](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html), and its general form is `s/regexp/replacement/flags` where "regexp" stands for "regular expression".
In the above example, the script looks for the string "id = ..." with any number of spaces or tabs around the "=" character. I divided the regexp into 2 groups (using parentheses) because we only want to replace the part to the right of the "=" character, and I don't think `sed` allows partial substitutions, so as a workaround I used `\1` in the "replacement", which inserts the contents of the 1st group. The `${NEW_ID}` actually gets evaluated by the shell so the value of the variable ("1234") is already part of the string by the time `sed` processes it. The `g` at the end stands for "global" and is probably redundant in this case. It makes sure that all occurrences of the regex on every line will get replaced; otherwise `sed` would only replace the first occurrence on each line.

Comment: Thanks man! very helpful. Correct answer. Going to check what the parameters inside "" means

Comment: @IvanMacià No problem. I have updated the answer with some additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. Bash scripts are extremely sensitive. I'm guessing your touch is what is causing this issue for a couple of reasons.

First whenever you touch a file name is should not consist of an operand or prefix unliss it is part of the shell script and $filename is shell or inline block quote. Touch is usually used for binaries or high priority data objects.

Second I'd try changing input and adjusted to $done and instead of echoing the $line echo the entire script using esac or end if instead of a do while loop.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why do you say "Touch is usually used for binaries or high priority data objects."? touch is very often used to create an arbitrary file.

Comment: I edited some code, can you please review it? thanks